# How to change the default momentum arrow settings in TikZ-Feynman

Tags: luatex, tikz-feynman

I'm trying to change the color of every momentum arrow in Feynman diagrams generated with `tikz-feynman`.

You can customize each momentum arrow individually like this:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] { 
  i1 [particle=$e^-$] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=$e^+$],
  a -- [photon, momentum={[arrow style=red] $k$}] b,
  f1 [particle=$\mu^+$] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=$\mu^-$],
};

\end{document}
```

[image: Example Feynman diagram]

But I'd like to use `\tikzfeynmanset` to make this color default:

```
\tikzfeynmanset{
  every momentum/.append arrow style=red, % something like this
}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] { 
  i1 [particle=$e^-$] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=$e^+$],
  a -- [photon, momentum=$k$] b,
  f1 [particle=$\mu^+$] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=$\mu^-$],
};
```

which would produce the same image.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
\tikzfeynmanset{
    momentum/arrow style=red,
}
```

(see [manual](https://mirror.informatik.hs-fulda.de/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-feynman/tikz-feynman.pdf), section "3.2.5 Momentum Keys")

Comment: This worked! Thanks!

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 0):

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[convert]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\tikzfeynmanset{
  momentum/arrow style={red},
}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] { 
  i1 [particle=$e^-$] -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2 [particle=$e^+$],
  a -- [photon, momentum={$k$}] b,
  f1 [particle=$\mu^+$] -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2 [particle=$\mu^-$],
};

\end{document}
```

[image]